# Alternatives to body onload - doesn't seem to initialise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/ur3csb8g/1/

I'm only able to enter my code snippet into the body of a website and not modify the body tag itself to call the initialise function to call google map.

I tried to be smart and wrap everything in this tag:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
//code
}
```

However the google map code no longer runs. Can anyone show me where I am going wrong please. I've used code from tutorials so that should be ok but the bit's I've changed obviously aren't :(

Comment: Try reading the error Console in your browser's developer tools — *Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list* — and providing a test case *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave a callback to the google map api fetch, but that function didn't exist. Try replacing `$(document).ready(function()` with `function initMap()`

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ur3csb8g/3/

Comment: That looks good, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors in your code. First you call the google api with a callback Methode initMap which doesn't exists. Next you wrap the complete method initialize in an anonymous function. Finally you have an nesting error:

```
// name it like you call the api...
function initMap() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.520266, 73.856406);
      var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.579943, 77.330006);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var myOptions2 = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
      var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_2"), myOptions2);
      var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: "Pune"
      });
      var myMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng2,
        map: map2,
        title: "Noida"
      });
    }

// wrap only the execution here...
$(document).ready(function() {
    initMap();
});
```

[Working variant here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ur3csb8g/8/)